# Getting Class not found: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Deployment when I try to deploy an App to Kubernetes Cluster from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jackson

I have a Jenkins job that is pointing to GitHub with webhook enabled. So whenever there is a push to the branch, the build should be triggered and the images should be pushed to docker.
During the deployment phase to K8S cluster, I am getting the below error. Few forums suggest to downgrade JacksonApi to lower version, but when I do that, other plugins stop working as they require the latest version (2.12.0).

How do I resolve this?

`ERRORS:`

```
ERROR: ERROR: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Deployment; exception=Class not found: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Deployment
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
    apiVersion: apps/v1

Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Class not found: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Deployment
```

Comment: I have the same problem, how you solve this problem?

Comment: I used Jenkins docker image

Comment: Do you have a jenkinsFile exemple to send ? because  I still couldn't fix my file